# rsync exclude-from directory with space

Tags: rsync, quoting

I am trying to exclude "Mendeley Desktop" directory for rsync.

The exclude-from= is as:

```
Downloads
*.o
*.iso
Dropbox
Documents/Mendeley\ Desktop
```

but rsync is still backing up the Mendeley Desktop.

How I can make rsync to ignore the directories with space?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove the `\` from before the space.  An escaped space is used to stop the shell splitting at spaces.  As you are using a file to list your excluded directories and files then the words `Mendeley Desktop` will never pass through the shell and therefore will not need escaping.  If you were listing them on the command line with `--exclude` then you'd need to escape the space.

Use:

```
Downloads
*.o
*.iso
Dropbox
Documents/Mendeley Desktop
```